# How to replace a value in the original dataframe while looping through its rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I know it's a bad to loop through rows in a df, but I have a column of lists of a couple hundred rows in which I need to modify each element within the list. I'm having a hard time using the .str.replace()/.strip() in a way that deals with all the extra spaces etc. The is the input:

```
import pandas as pd

input_19 = [{'name':'Hector', 'team_position':'forward', 'player_traits':'Finesse Shot, Speed Dribbler (CPU AI Only)'}, {'name':'Bysim', 'team_position':'forward', 'player_traits':'Long Shot Taker (CPU AI Only)'}, {'name':'Nicolas', 'team_position':'defender', 'player_traits':'Beat Offside Trap, Finesse Shot'}]

input_20 = [{'name':'Johann', 'team_position':'gk', 'player_traits':'GK Long Throw'}, {'name':'Winston', 'team_position':'defender', 'player_traits':'Dives Into Tackles (CPU AI Only)'}, {'name':'Petr', 'team_position':'forward', 'player_traits':'Flair, Long Shot Taker (CPU AI Only)'}]

df_19 = pd.DataFrame(input_19)
df_20 = pd.DataFrame(input_20)
```

output:

df_19:

```
    name     player_traits                               team_position
0   Hector   Finesse Shot, Speed Dribbler (CPU AI Only)  forward
1   Bysim    Long Shot Taker (CPU AI Only)               forward
2   Nicolas  Beat Offside Trap , Finesse Shot            defender
```

df_20:

```
    name     player_traits                               team_position
0   Johann   GK Long Throw                               gk
1   Winston  Dives Into Tackles (CPU AI Only)            defender
2   Petr     Flair,  Long Shot Taker (CPU AI Only)       forward
```

The 'player_traits' column in both dfs need string modification, as mentioned above, so I can count their frequency. I would like to modify them in the original df (which is by year) so I can create new dfs by filtering with 'team_position' and use Counter to find the totals of each trait/element. This is the code I have but I'm not sure how to assign the new 'temp_list' to the appropriate place in the original df since .loc combined with a .replace() modifies a slice of the dataframe, and .replace() for dfs take in only string arguments:

```
df_list = [df_19, df_20]

for df in df_list:
    for lst,i in zip(df['player_traits'].values, range(len(df['player_traits'].values))):
        temp_list = []
        if type(lst) != float:
            lst = lst.replace('(CPU AI Only)',"")
            lst = lst.split(",")
            for x in lst:
                x = x.strip()
                temp_list.append(x)
         # df[location of original value in original df] = temp_list
         # something like:
         # df[i, 'player_traits'] = temp_list
```

How can I complete this code that allows me to modify the original df value with the modified list?

Comment: you could write function which makes all changes in string and later use `.apply()` without loop to run it on all rows. It will works the same way as with loop but it can be faster. And then you use `df['player_traits'] = df['player_traits'].apply(your_function)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create function which gets string, changes it and returns your list and later use it with `.apply()` without loop.

```
df['player_traits'] = df['player_traits'].apply(my_function)
```

---

Working example

```
import pandas as pd

# --- function ---

def my_function(lst):
    temp_list = []

    if type(lst) != float:
        lst = lst.replace('(CPU AI Only)',"")
        lst = lst.split(",")
        for x in lst:
            x = x.strip()
            temp_list.append(x)

    return temp_list

# --- main ---

input_19 = [{'name':'Hector', 'team_position':'forward', 'player_traits':'Finesse Shot, Speed Dribbler (CPU AI Only)'}, {'name':'Bysim', 'team_position':'forward', 'player_traits':'Long Shot Taker (CPU AI Only)'}, {'name':'Nicolas', 'team_position':'defender', 'player_traits':'Beat Offside Trap, Finesse Shot'}]
input_20 = [{'name':'Johann', 'team_position':'gk', 'player_traits':'GK Long Throw'}, {'name':'Winston', 'team_position':'defender', 'player_traits':'Dives Into Tackles (CPU AI Only)'}, {'name':'Petr', 'team_position':'forward', 'player_traits':'Flair, Long Shot Taker (CPU AI Only)'}]

df_19 = pd.DataFrame(input_19)
df_20 = pd.DataFrame(input_20)

df_list = [df_19, df_20]

for df in df_list:
    df['player_traits'] = df['player_traits'].apply(my_function)

print(df_19)
print(df_20)
```

Comment: But how can I apply 3 functions with one .apply(), (replacing '(CPU AI Only)', splitting into a list, and then stripping the whitespace from each element)?

Comment: you have all 3 functions inside `my_function()` so you have to `apply()` only one function - `apply(my_function)`. See working example in answer.